# my sql server query can't return expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have this query :

```
select 
 Receptions.SubmitDatetime as SubmitReceptionDatetime
 ,Receptions.ExpirePetrolDatetime as ExpireDatetime 
   from Receptions
```

The result :

[image]

But i want to find a specific date in my result as you  can see :

```
 select 
 Receptions.SubmitDatetime as SubmitReceptionDatetime
 ,Receptions.ExpirePetrolDatetime as ExpireDatetime 
   from Receptions 
 where 

   ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime >=CONVERT(datetime,'8-1-2017'))
 and  ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime <=CONVERT(datetime,'8-1-2017'))
 order by Receptions.id desc
```

But it doesn't return any records why ?

Comment: Probably date format day-month-year vs month-day-year. Try with `Receptions.SubmitDatetime >= '20170801'`

Comment: Try running `SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'8-1-2017')` and see if it returns the value you expect - the trouble is you have picked an ambiguous date format that could be interpreted as 8th January or 1st August. Try providing in the universal `YYYYMMDD` format?

Comment: @Bridge the query returns this 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: my correct datetime is 1 august 2017

Comment: @Bridge no i don't need expire that ,i just want to find the registered receptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with time part:

```
select 
 Receptions.SubmitDatetime as SubmitReceptionDatetime
 ,Receptions.ExpirePetrolDatetime as ExpireDatetime 
   from Receptions 
 where 

   ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime >= '2017-08-01T00:00:00'
 and  ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime <='2017-08-01T23:59:59')
 order by Receptions.id desc
```

Your origial query is equivalent to:

```
Receptions.SubmitDatetime = '2017-08-01T00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you it works ,but i don't want to include time to my query

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you convert a string to a date time, the time is midnight. See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

So, you're asking for records both before AND after midnight on 1 August. Those do not exist.

Assuming you want records for 8 August:

```
 select 
 Receptions.SubmitDatetime as SubmitReceptionDatetime
 ,Receptions.ExpirePetrolDatetime as ExpireDatetime 
   from Receptions 
 where 

   ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime >=CONVERT(datetime,'8-1-2017'))
 and  ( Receptions.SubmitDatetime <=CONVERT(datetime,'9-1-2017'))
 order by Receptions.id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
select 
 Receptions.SubmitDatetime as SubmitReceptionDatetime
 ,Receptions.ExpirePetrolDatetime as ExpireDatetime 
  from Receptions 
where 
convert(varchar(8),Receptions.SubmitDatetime,112)='20170801'
 order by Receptions.id desc
```

Your 'Receptions.SubmitDatetime' contains time so you need to convert that back to just the date as the example above does.

Comment: One drawback of this method is that this expression `convert(varchar(8),Receptions.SubmitDatetime,112)='20170801'` is not SARG-able.